# Calculating the settling time of lowpass and bandpass SOS filters constructured using SciPy

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, filter-design, bandpass, highpass-filter

I have constructed a high pass filter using scipy:

```
l_freq = 0.1
fs = 500
normal_cutoff = l_freq / (0.5 * fs)
sos = butter(4, normal_cutoff, btype = 'high', output = 'sos')
scipy_iir_continuous_data = sosfilt(sos, data)
```

As well as a bandpass filter using scipy:

```
l_freq = 1
h_freq = 4
normal_cutoff = [l_freq / (0.5 * fs), h_freq / (0.5 * fs)]
sos = butter(4, normal_cutoff, btype = 'bandpass', output = 'sos')
scipy_iir_continuous_data = sosfilt(sos, data)
```

I would like to calculate an approximate settling time, or number of samples I need to filter and then discard to arrive at an approximate steady state.

I looked at this [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/83873/what-is-the-relationship-among-digital-filter-cutoff-frequency-signal-frequency) as well as this old [thesis](https://stars.library.ucf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5710&context=rtd) (which seem to have different solutions), but can't figure out how to apply a general settling time formula for a high pass, a low pass, and a bandpass filter given the sampling frequency and the cutoff frequencies.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here is also an [interesting approach](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17121/calculation-of-reverberation-time-rt60-from-the-impulse-response/17123#17123) for estimating the settling time via Schroeder Integration method. However, no matter which solution, the estimation of settling time in the context of IIR filters also depends on a threshold (like the 60dB for accoustics, or a certain % of rise time).  My additional question regarding this subject would be how to choose this threshold?

Comment: I found this [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/77005/estimating-reverberant-time-t60-of-an-iir-filter/77009?noredirect=1#comment191581_77009) and the answers also very educative regarding settling time.